# Error connecting nodejs app to heroku clear DB

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku

I have a nodeJS + mysql app that works fine on local, but when I try to connect it to an Heroku clear DB database I'm getting error. Database credentials are ok because I'm using them same on another web app.

This is my connection code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql2');
var cnx = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'us-cdbr-east-xx.cleardb.com',
    user: 'bb69add9159975',
    password: 'fb0xxxxx',
    database: 'heroku_65f44b5a5fxxxx',
    multipleStatements: true
});

cnx.connect(err => {
    if(!err){
        console.log(`Database connection successful`);
    }else{
        console.log(`Databse connection failed: ${err}`);
    }
});

module.exports = cnx;
```

This is the error on console:

Databse connection failed: Error: Access denied for user 'bb69add9159975'@'ip-10-0-125-110.ec2.internal' (using password: YES)

Thanks.

Comment: Have you allowed this IP in the DB ips whitelist?

Comment: Didn't know about that or how to do it

Comment: (It)[https://help.heroku.com/JS13Y78I/i-need-to-add-heroku-dynos-to-our-allowlist-what-are-ip-address-ranges-in-use-at-heroku] is not exact match, but somehow helps you.

Comment: I think I find out what the problem is. My node app does not have an cleardb addon, I'm trying to connect to another heroku app database intead. How could I do that?